# Product of $L^2$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis

If $ \Omega$ is any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that the product of two $L^2$ functions over $\Omega$ is also $L^2$ ? What about $L^p $ ?

Comment: If I remember right, $L^p$ is an algebra for any $p \geq 1$...

Comment: You might consider functions of one variable and consider $\Omega=(0,1)$.

Comment: In particular, on $(0,1)$ consider $x^{-1/4}$ and its square.

Comment: Take $f(x)=g(x)=x^{-1/4}$ on $(0,1)$.  Then $\int_0^1f^2(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 g^2(x)\,dx=2$.  But clearly $\int_0^1 f^2(x)g^2(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

Answer (score 11):

No. In fact, the following is easy to prove for $p \ge 2$:
a function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ belongs to $L^p(\Omega)$ if and only if $f^2 \in L^{p/2}(\Omega)$.

Now, you obtain a counterexample to your question by choosing a function $f \in L^2(\Omega) \setminus L^4(\Omega)$.

Comment: Should it be $f\in L^2(\Omega)\backslash L^4(\Omega)$?

Comment: @geometricK: Yes, of course. Thank you!